# symfony @oneToMany relation returns only last object in collection

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a situation and not really sure what I'm doing wrong. in Sumfony 3.3 I've created a relation between entity Page and Language, where Page is related to multiple Languages, and when I search for a Page and get Page object but property Languages returns collection with only last Language object. No matter how many objects are there in collection it always returns last.

Page Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Language", mappedBy="page", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="page_id")
 */
private $languages;
```

Language entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="languages")
 */
private $page;

public function addLanguage(\AppBundle\Entity\Langaugee $language)
{
    $this->languages[] = $language;

    return $this;
}

public function removeLanguage(\AppBundle\Entity\Language $language)
{
    $this->$languages->removeElement($language);
}

public function getLanguages()
{
    return $this->languages;
}
```

Page object is fetching in PageService:

```
public function getPageByName($name)
{
return $this->pageRepository->findBy(array("name"=>$name));
}
```

Since property $languages by default set on lazy, JMS serializer when serializes Page object it's fetching languages collection

Did anyone had this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code where you do the `$page->getLanguages()` and the code of your `function getLanguages()`?

Comment: yes i've updated question, and JMS serializer is fetching languages

Comment: Well post the relevant portion of code ^^ If we don't know how you get your objects we can't help. We are not magicians (yet)

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, I've posted code in PageService. And I'm using FOS rest bundle and JMS serializer so in controller I'm using view method from FOSController in MyController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough debugging, I figure it out that indexBy is misused here. Defined indexBy = page_id provided always the same value so every record that is mapped to entity in SimpleObjectHydrator overrun the existing record, leaving only last added Language object in collection

Answer (score 0):

I know Its an old post, but solution below worked for me.

I had to clear EntityManager cache in my repository class method by calling this method just before fetching data.

```
$this->_em->clear();
```

here `_em` is the default `EntityManager` available in the repository class.